# Como puedo colocar un mismo pie de pagina en cada una de las paginas de un pdf generado por medio de HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

Tengo una consulta, y es como puedo colocar un mismo pie de pagina sin necesidad de estar colocando uno por uno en un código HTML, ya que puede aveces generarme saltos de paginas innecesarios. la cuestión es colocar el mismo pie de pagina por cada una de las paginas que se generen, si necesito de algún código de css, de JavaScript? me pueden ayudar con esta duda

[image]

Colocamos el codigo html en el aplicativo, estos viajan a una tabla el cual contiene cada uno de los documentos que se van a mostrar.

Comment: Sería de utilidad que muestres algo de tú código y proporciones de que manera estás generando el PDF, si utilizas alguna librería o algo por el estilo.

Comment: tenemos un aplicativo en el cual colocamos el codigo html y generamos los documentos en pdf

Comment: yo manejo la parte de la base de datos mas que el aplicativo por temas de acceso, ademas que el aplicativo no quieren realizar cambios.

Comment: igual si crees que es posible o no lo que te comento, me ayudarias mucho

Comment: y el codigo? que lenguaje usas para crear los pdf... faltan mas antecedente para poder aydar